# Why doesn't AWS X-Ray show errors?

Tags: amazon-web-services, error-handling, aws-lambda, aws-xray

1. I really would like to integrate X-Ray with my distributed application, but I have concerns about its debugging capabilities. I use Lambda proxy integration with Node.js. How can I make X-Ray to show the client errors (4xx) arising from a `new Error()` object, in the trace -> Exceptions section or anywhere else where I can see and root cause the error?
2. I have deployed a simple Lambda proxy integration that writes a file to s3 and a record to DynamoDB. However upon calling the function, I get 502 Bad Gateway error. AWS X-Ray Service Map shows that lambda function has error, but interestingly, it doesn't show any error in the Exception list. After going through Cloudwatch logs, I realised that it's because lambda functions time out. But going through CW logs is a tedious work, and one of the purpose of X-Ray is to ease debugging. So, I'm wondering how can I show more precise errors to easily debugging the app (in this case, time out error)?

You can find screenshots of my X-Ray: X-Ray Service Map indicates there is error
[image: X-Ray Service Map indicates there is error]

Trace indicates there is an error
[image: Trace indicates there is an error]

But trace doesn't show the error
[image: But trace doesn't show the error]